# executing scripts

Tags: unix, scripting, bin

I have a folders containing a bunch of scripts. Suppose the folder is at `~/scripts`

Is there a way I can execute those scripts in the directory easily without having to do something like `~/scripts/file1.sh` ? I've tried putting the scripts in `/bin/`, but then I'd still have to do `file1.sh`. Is there a way I can just refer to those scripts by their name, without the extension (ie., `file1`) ?

Thanks.

Comment: Why not name the scripts without `.sh`?

Comment: Just for the sake of convenience. Also most the scripts I have in their are more like utility commands.

Comment: Yes but why not just rename the file to `file1`? then you wont need to type the `.sh` part. If the scripts are marked as executable and has a proper `#!`-line there is not need to have a `.sh` extension.

Comment: Aah, I didn't know that! I thought all scripts need to end with `.sh`

Comment: Nope no need for any extension. When you execute a file the kernel will do some signature checks to determine how to execute it (if possible) and in the case of scripts, whether it is a shell, ruby, python scripts etc they all start the file with `#!` and after that the path to the actual file to execute with the script file as argument.

Comment: the `file` command is also a way to determine the file type (though it's not always 100% accurate) still a good command to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `~/scripts` to your PATH env variable either in .profile, .bashrc or on command line itself. Use following command to change your PATH env variable:

```
export PATH=$PATH:~/scripts
```

Once that is done make sure your scripts have execute permissions using `chmod +x file` command, then you can execute:

```
file1.sh
file2.sh
```

i.e. without prefixing with actual path of these scripts.

Comment: Ok, so I added the path to my PATH variable. HOw do I make the change permanent? I don't want to set the path every time I open a terminal. Thanks

Comment: To make change permanent add `export PATH=$PATH:~/scripts` to your `~/.profile` or `~/.bashrc` file. After making the change logout and login again.

Comment: I tried opening `~/.profile` and `~/.bashrc`, but got "No such file or directory" error.

Comment: `.profile` may not exist but you can of course create a new one and add above command there. btw do you know which shell are you using?

Comment: No. but I'm assuming Bourne Shell. Becuase the sheabang of the scripts are `#! /bin/sh`.

Comment: Better to create `.profile` which will work whether it is bash or sh.

Comment: The `#!` in a script specifies which interpreter (shell) is used to execute that script. That's unrelated to what your *interactive* shell is; that's specified in your `/etc/passwd` entry.

Answer (score 0):

Not an optimal solution if you want to run many scripts, but you could create aliases for your most frequently used scripts. I also name my shell scripts with the `.sh` extension for documentation purposes (ie easy to spot when doing a `ls`).

This way the alias is the name of the script without the .sh extension, but invokes the script by directly referring to my own `~/bin` directory.

One of the nice things about this OS is that there are always many ways to accomplish a task, it can't hurt to have multiple approaches in your toolbox in case one doesn't work some day.